# My Glassfish Exception report HTTP Status 500 -

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, postgresql, glassfish

message

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean entryDataPegawaiBean
root cause

com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean entryDataPegawaiBean
root cause

com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting invoke lifecycle  method private void com.pelindo.simpers.bean.EntryDataPegawaiBean.construct()
root cause

com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting invoke lifecycle  method private void com.pelindo.simpers.bean.EntryDataPegawaiBean.construct()
root cause

java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
root cause

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
root cause

javax.ejb.EJBException
root cause

Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function right(character varying, integer) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 75
Error Code: 0
root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function right(character varying, integer) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 75

Part of my been class :

public class EntryDataPegawaiBean implements Serializable {

```
PegawaiFacadeRemote pegawaiFacade = lookupPegawaiFacadeRemote();
PegawaiKhususFacadeRemote pegawaiKhususFacade = lookupPegawaiKhususFacadeRemote();
AlamatHistFacadeRemote alamatFacade = lookupAlamatHistFacadeRemote();
CatatanHistFacadeRemote catatanFacade = lookupCatatanHistFacadeRemote();
@EJB
PendidikanFacadeRemote pendidikanFacadeRemote;
@EJB
UniverTblFacadeRemote univerTblFacadeRemote;
@EJB
BiayaiTblFacadeRemote biayaiTblFacadeRemote;
@EJB
JnsNformalTblFacadeRemote jnsNformalTblFacadeRemote;
@EJB
NegaraTblFacadeRemote negaraTblFacadeRemote;
@EJB
MasterSettingAppFacadeRemote masterSettingAppFacade;
......
```

// logic with method

Comment: What's your PostgreSQL version?

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL 9.0 [doesn't have a `right` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-string.html). It was [added in 9.1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html). That's why the error says:

> function right(character varying, integer) does not exist

Upgrade, or work around it with `length` and `substring` instead.

In future, always include your PostgreSQL version in questions please - as you can see, it's relevant.